# Many to Many relation in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I have user and job model. their is many to many relation between them. Name of Pivot table in job_user. I want to store records in pivot table with job Type and job Title from Job table and user Name from user table. how will i store that?Here is relation between job and user.

Job Model

```
public function Job_User()
{
    return $this->belongs To Many('App\Http\Models\User', 'jobs_users', 'user_id', 'job_id')->with-pivot('user Name','job Type','job Title');;

}
```

My user Model

```
public function Job_User()
{
    return $this->belongs To Many('App\HTTP\Models\Job', 'jobs_users', 'user_id', 'job_id')->with Pivot('user Name','job Type','job Title');

}
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't store anything other than the keys in the pivot table. Its purpose isn't to store anything else.

Comment: But i have to store that.

Comment: is their any way???

Comment: You don't store that data in the pivot table. The user name goes in the user table, and the job title and type go in the job table. By binding job to user, or user to job, it creates a record in the pivot table. Once bound you can access your jobs ( if from user ) by doing `$user = User::find(1)->jobs`

Comment: when i am saving id of job and user as foreign key in pivot table i also want to store the jobtype and tile from job and user name from user. i have created the extra columns in pivot table.

Comment: $trai = $req->$trainer_id;
        $job = $req->job_id;
        $j = Job::find($job);
        foreach ($req->student as $key) {
            $stud = User::find($key);
            $stud->Job_User()->attach($job, ['trainer_id' => $trai,'userName'=>$stud->userName,'jobType'=>$job->jobType]);

        }

Comment: this is my controller function

Comment: [See second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566675/getting-the-value-of-an-extra-pivot-table-column-laravel) this may help.

Comment: Looks like you have it.  The second parameter is an array of updates to send to the pivot table.  Is it not working for you?

Comment: While you can absolutely store data in extra columns in the pivot table (see withPivot() which is designed to access this data), they are correct to say that you shouldn't be storing any user data or job data in the users_jobs table, as the pivot table should only store info relevant to the actual pivot (such as when the pivot was made, etc.)

Comment: no,its not working while i am storing the job records in pivot table