# How to access the fields in the table in many-to-many intermediate tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

How to access the fields in the table in many-to-many intermediate tables?

What kind of eloqunet builder is required to access the **isAlternative** field in the table named category_product?

**Category table**

```
categories
 - id
 - name
```

**Product table**

```
products
 - id
 - name
 - price
```

**CategoryProduct table**

```
category_product
 - category_id
 - product_id
 - isAlternative
```

Comment: `withPivot('isAlternative')` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: what have you tried so far? what error are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting the value of an extra pivot table column laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566675/getting-the-value-of-an-extra-pivot-table-column-laravel)